# Macro stopping at print PDF code

Tags: pdf, excel, excel-2010, vba

We use a single machine to run our `VBA` macros.
Last week we changed machine - to a virtual "server" running Windows 7: I'll use the term server quite loosely as it is more like a virtualised-pc.

Everything is running smoothly apart from one line of code:

```
Excel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=FilePath_pdf & FileName_pdf, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=2, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Unfortunately the error message reported when it bugs is not descriptive and if I go into debug mode and hit `F8` then it runs the line ok!

It is running under the credentials of a network login not my network login.
This login is the same one we used for our previous non-virtual excel box.

Is there some software I need to double-check is installed on the new box?
Is there an alternative approach i could take to move the contents of this file into a `pdf` file?

Comment: And the not descriptive error is? You go into debug mode on that 'server'? Does it run under your credentials? Which Excel version?

Comment: @rene - I've added some more detail: XL-2010; runs under the credentials of a network login that we used on the previous box. I've re-scheduled the job and once the error has been reproduced I will paste in the error message (unfortunately not easy to reproduce because if I step through the code it executes ok)

Comment: Have you considered adding an error handling, so the error is at list printed to the Immediate output?

Comment: @Juliusz - no, not considered. Is that easy to implement? Do I just add `on  error resume next` before the statement and then `debug.print err.message` after the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note to third parties: it is not the answer to the problem]

Example of an error handling:

```
Public Sub Boo(ByVal Calendar As Variant)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Dim sProcedureName As String: sProcedureName = "Boo"

  'Code here

ExitProcedure:
  On Error Resume Next
  'Final termination here
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  Debug.Print "Error """ & Err.Description & """ in " & sProcedureName
  GoTo ExitProcedure:
  Resume 'used for debugging, never hit in run time

End Sub
```